# Problema impressão de tabela

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma tabela de produtos e estou montando o layout dela para impressão.
Estou utilizando a tag  para que o titulo das colunas se repita a cada nova página na impressão porém o cliente não gostou do resultado que aparece no print abaixo.

Esse bloco de texto em lorem ipsum será a descrição do produto, e o titulo das colunas está aparecendo em cima dele após a quebra de página, mas o cliente quer que apareça somente em cima dos itens codigo, nome e descrição.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem acima, no item 1 o bloco de texto é do item da página anterior, nãou coube na página e naturalmente foi pra página seguinte. E o item 2, o titulo das colunas (cod, name, descrição) deveriam estar abaixo da descrição do item anterior.
Já tentei usar o page-break-after do css para fazer a quebra porém não funcionou. Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Felipe, se possível poste a parte do código responsável por isso, ou até mesmo uma simulação(interno) disso junto a sua pergunta ou um JSFIDDLE (externo).

Comment: Segue o link no jsbin: https://jsbin.com/weratiwova/1/edit?html,css,output Mas de qualquer forma tem que mandar imprimir para visualizar a impressão e poder visualizar o problema.

Comment: Rapaz, vou te falar que esse é um problema bem cabeludo... dei uma pesquisada, e muita solução é extremamente esotérica. Talvez seja melhor você pensar em outra forma de imprimir essas tabelas, talvez gerar um ``.doc`` ou contar as linhas e criar a quebra de página na unha...

Comment: Concordo com vc, saiba que usei o stackoverflow depois de ter tentado várias coisas. Mas blz, vou aguardar mais um pouco e se não der em nada fecho essa pergunta. Agradeço aos que comentaram até agora.

Comment: Entrei na luta. Vou ver se acho algo! Haha... Mas até onde eu sei, acho que o mais fácil pra essa solução (não aplicável em tabelas) é o esquema de `widows` e `orphans`.

Comment: É... vou mentir não. Em tabela parece brabo mesmo.